Sequentially changing the intensity of emission on a series of lights
I'm trying to reproduce the effect of lights turning on one after the other so that the light seems to be jumping from one lamp to the next. I'm using an emission shader. I've succeeded in doing it by keyframing and moving my keyframes by one frame on each successive object but I suspect there is a more elegant and procedural wat to do it but cannot figure it out. 

Drive wave texture based on object position
You can use the same shader on all your objects, and drive a Wave texture based on their position. This solution will get you only one value per object, meaning the whole object has only one emission value. No gradient will appear on the lights.
We can use Object Info > Location to get the position of the object in the scene. This output has no notion of geometry or mesh, it's only the position of the object.
Before using these positions to drive the texture, we can animated it with a Mapping node. Basically we move the positions along the same axis as the wave texture.
Finally we plug it into the Wave texture, with probably a very small Scale. Here are the nodes and the animation :


Additionnal note
In my experience, shaders are all about playing with coordinates, find how to drive things automatically in creative ways. If you repeat the same task manualy multiple times, it may be the clue that there is some automation to be done.

That's a smart way of doing it @Lutzi
